# Graphics are messed up after recent update (mesa and wayland)

Tags: updates, graphics

After this update:

```
>     Start-Date: 2020-03-07  10:47:18
>     Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.495'
>     Upgrade: libgles2-mesa:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libglapi-mesa:i386
> (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3),
> libxatracker2:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2,
> 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libgbm1:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3),
> libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2,
> 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3),
> libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2,
> 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), unattended-upgrades:amd64 (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.13, 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.14), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64
> (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3),
> mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2,
> 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3), libglx-mesa0:i386 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3)
>     End-Date: 2020-03-07  10:47:29
```

I started seeing strange things with various graphics operation like parts of the screen not getting redrawn, cheese displays complete garbage above the diagonal from top-left to bottom-right and sometimes the bottom side has weird artifacts as well.  Resizing a window will sometimes make missing graphics reappear.

Has anybody else seen this?  I am using an HP Envy with Core I7 and Nvidia, 16 GiB Ram.  I tried both nvidia and nouveau drivers and don't see much difference between them with this problem.

Is there an easy way too undo this update (or everything back to this update)?

-- Todd

*A little bit of an update*:

Oddly, cheese now seems to be working correctly.  This is good because I can now use my microscope again to see images on my laptop screen.  I don't know what changed, but I did notice some of the i386 versions from the update above were deleted when I ran 'apt autoremove'.  There were also some recent unattended-upgrade lines which have appeared in the history.log file.

Most of the graphics problems have cleared up, but a few minor ones remain.  Suduku, for example, doesn't display anything but a blank canvas until you resize the window to smaller size.  Some menus have short horizontal lines when they are displayed.